# DB::transaction is not working as exptected in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, transactions

I Have couple of sql queries which I had to bind in transaction so that if any one of the query fails it would go to initial so for that I just did this here is the code..

```
  DB::beginTransaction();

        try {
            //update loan application
            $loanApplication->status = 'DISBURSED';
            $loanApplication->tenure = $offerDetails['tenure'];
            $loanApplication->amount_offered = $offerDetails['loanAmount'];

            $isUpdated = $loanApplication->update();

            //create loan disbursal
            LoanDisbursal::insertGetId([
                'created_dt' => Carbon::now(),
                'user_id' => $loanApplication->user_id,
                'loan_account' => $loanApplication->application_id,
            ]);

            //create loan profile account
            ProfilesHasAccount::insertGetId([
                'user_id' => $loanApplication->user_id,
                'gateway' => $this->gatewayAlias,
                'account_segment' => 'BUSINESS',
                'account_type' => 'LOAN',
                'created_dt' => Carbon::now(),
                'status' => 'ACTIVE',
            ]);

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            dd(DB::rollback());
            dd($th);
        }

        DB::commit();
```

Now acccording to the transaction if any one of the query fails it must rollback all the completed sql operation but it is not happening here

any ideas or suggestions , would be very helpful

Comment: you should use DB::commit at the end of the try block and get DB:: rollback() out of dd

Comment: @BhargavRangani I tried that too

Comment: @RohannnSingh what is your MySQL version, and database table engine you have ?

Comment: Actually MySQL does include support for transactions through the InnoDB storage engine which is bundled with MySQL. It's not the default storage engine but that setting can be changed. Or you can simply specify the engine when creating your tables.

Comment: @NomanYousaf i am using innoDB for my tables also mysql  version -> Ver 8.0.30 for macos12.4 on x86_64 (Homebrew)

Answer (score 0):

OKAY I found the answer and the problem was my projects contains multiple datbases so I just had to show connections on transactions like this

```
DB::connection('ipay_app_loans__write')->beginTransaction();

DB::connection('ipay_app_loans__write')->rollBack();

DB::connection('ipay_app_loans__write')->commit();
```

That's it!!